# Stereographic projection with de Sitter space and hyperbolic plane

Tags: differential-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry, stereographic-projections

How can we do stereographic projection using de Sitter space $\Bbb S^2_1$ and the hyperbolic plane $\Bbb H^2$, in Lorentz-Minkowski space $\Bbb L^3$.

For $\Bbb S^2_1$ it is not clear what point should be used as a pole, and for $\Bbb H^2$ it seems that using $(0,0, 1)$ doesn't work (I put the minus sign last in the metric here). I don't think it is much related to the isometry between the hyperboloid model and the Klein model, either.

I looked around a bit but found nothing. It would be nice if there's a way to generalize the stereographic projection to pseudo-spheres in spaces of arbitrary index $\Bbb R^n_\nu$, but I'll be happy with the cases above. I want to use this to study Weierstrass representations of critical surfaces in $\Bbb L^3$. Thanks.

Comment: In case this is of interest: Projection from the origin maps the future-pointing unit timelike vectors (not the deSitter space) to the Klein model of the hyperbolic plane (embedded in Minkowski space as the open unit disk in the plane $z = 1$), while projection from $(0, 0, -1)$ maps the same (half-)hyperboloid to the Poincaré model (embedded as the open unit disk in the plane $z = 0$).

Answer (score 1):

[This report](http://www.math.illinois.edu/igl/Projects-Spring2013/spacesphere_report.pdf) uses $(0,0,-1)$, and de Sitter lines become hyperbolas. Klein model projects de Sitter lines to line fragments outside the circle.

Of course, with computer graphics you can project de Sitter plane to a finite height cylinder, using unit circle instead of single point pole. Can't say if this projection has any notable property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "On the Generalized Stereographic Projection",Baki Karliga , Beitrage zur Algebra und Geometrie (Contributions to Algebra and Geometry) Volume 37 (1996), No. 2, 329-336.

Comment: This is more of a reference than an actual answer and should be entered as a comment when you have enough reputation